# ISOWEEKNUM and WEEKNUM function giving back wrong value

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to convert a date into a week number, which should be simple, only it's giving back value. Instead of the week number, it says 16/01/1900 00:00:00.

I used `=ISOWEEKNUM(C2)` and `=WEEKNUM(C2, 2)` and I tried it without time and in different date formats as well.

Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

[image: Screenshot of sheet]

Answer (score 3):

Issue is found, the cells of the week numbers had a date format, so I had to convert it into plain text. It works now!